# How to close CSS issue in IE 7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

```
#header-menu{
    width:990px;
    height: 115px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-top: 0px;
}
```

I am using this CSS Code which is working on every browser even IE9 , IE8.. But it is not working on IE7. I am not understanding what is problem

Comment: What is not working about it?

Comment: Do you have this line as is:`height: 115px;enter code here`

Comment: A [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be much better

Answer (score 0):

IE 7 has alway been a hassle when it comes to CSS. You could always add an extra style sheet to modify and change anything IE 7 is messing up in the HEAD of your document (just ensure that it is below your main style sheet):

```
<!--[if IE 7]><link href="/css/ie7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><![endif]-->
```

This isn't the fastest way, and the W3C would recommend that you pre-browser check and add a class to the body, in order to add to your style sheet, but it is the quickest, and gets the job done.

Note: We can only hope that we one day live in a world that doesn't support IE 7.

Comment: Yes , i have added this CSS file like you said...  But it still get distracted ... I am using above CSS in the ie7.css ...

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell us why is it not working? If you are trying to center something, then the `margin-left:auto;` and `margin-right:auto;` technique does not work on old IE versions, so you should use `text-align:center;` in the parent element (and not in the header-menu itself). If header-menu has no parent, then you should apply `text-align:center;` to the html element:

```
html {text-align:center;}
```

EDIT:
And since this is not elegant you may include that in a separate CSS for versions lower than IE8 with:

```
<!--[if lt IE8]> (your CSS here) <![endif]-->
```

Comment: <!--[if IE 7]>    <link href="css/ie7-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> <![endif]-->  in this CSS i have added above CSS code ... But it is not working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to center the `header-menu` as you have fixed width and height in this, you can use `margin: 0 auto;` instead of:

```
margin-top: 0px; margin-right: auto; margin-bottom: auto; margin-left: auto;
```

Hope this will solve your IE7 problem.